# Getting maximum column value in mysql

Tags: mysql

Basically I have:

```
            TableName
 ___________________________________________________________
| Amount |     ID     |            Phone    VARCHAR(45)     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |   Jack     | 780799870                           |
|   2    |   fob      | 121234567116105000137000000000000001|
|   3    |   AliClay  | 178234791827498789                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the maximum value of my phone column which is `120110117116105000137000000000000001`

but when i try `SELECT MAX(PHONE) FROM TableName;` I happen to get `780799870` as my result,

Comment: I suspect that you're simply after the MAX(LENGTH())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the value as a string -- which isn't surprising given that the numbers are so long.

Here is a simple way to get the record with the maximum value, assuming that the numbers never start with leading zeros (that can easily be included):

```
select t.*
from tablename t
order by length(phone) desc, phone desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

*It's just a proposal so let me know if doesn't work.*

You should cast the `varchar` to int to get the max:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(PHONE AS SIGNED))
FROM TableName
```

Comment: The datatype is probably overflowing.